# How can I send a NULL in Ruby Sockets?

Tags: ruby, sockets, null

I'm working on a socket app in Ruby Shoes, and want to send a message to the server.  The server expects the XML message, and then a null (0) character.

How can I send that in TCP Sockets in Ruby?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my own answer... The problem was not sending the NULL, it was a thread issue.

You can send a NULL as part of a string by just concatenating it on to the end of the string...

NULL = "\000"

...
tc = tc + "</endtag>"

tc = tc + NULL

Socket.send(tc, 0)

Comment: This works great, but because NULL starts with upper case N, it should go outside of any function, otherwise make it start with lowercase

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm not a Ruby person, so I was unaware of any style issues with the code snippet.  Thanks for clarifying it for me.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you use this inside a function, ruby will throw: "SyntaxError: dynamic constant assignment".  So it's more than just a style issue :)

Comment: I was using it in a GUI environment (Ruby Shoes, RIP), and it was not in a function.  Now I use Lua (Love2D).  Duh.  Didn't notice, it's in the Question.